# What is the diameter of each stage of the PW800 engine compressor and turbine?

Tags: jet-engine, engine-design, turbine, compressor

I am an Aerospace Engineering student working to analyze P&WC's PW800 engine family--specifically, the PW814GA, for a project and we need to know some hard-to-find data.
Does anyone knows where I could found out the diameter of each stage of the PW814GA fan, compressor and turbine? Or those of any similar engines so we can guess it? Thanks!

Comment: I’m pretty sure exact radius changes through a compressor or turbine are not public. Anyway it is surprising that you need this kind of data for a student project, maybe you can give us some precision about it ?

Comment: Blame my prof, what he want to do is exactly what i said. Analyze the PW800 engine. I don't need to ask this question here if I am a villain trying to do bad things.

Comment: I do not accuse you from spying at all. Analyzing an engine is broad and highly complex thats why I’m asking more details and why you need this specific dimension (seems useless for student but again I don’t know what your project is).

Comment: If your projet is literally « Analyze the PW800 engine », I recommend you to edit your question in order to ask some guidelines that we could give you to find engine characteristics: for instance, how to link By pass ratio with fan diameter, thrust, and other performance (OPR, Power, efficiency, etc..) or other interesting details for engineers